# Starting Search From a Specific Index

Tags: mysql

I am not a pro in the database sector so pardon me if i am asking a basic question.

### Scenario

I have a table in which **all the recorded are stored chronologically**. 
Number of rows of that table is 1,445,248 (***1.4 Million***).

### Desire

I want to optimize my query which looks like following: -

```
Select * from SalesInvoice where S_Date Between 20190401 And 20190501
```

**Note**

- Yes, i need all the columns in the table and instead of typing out all the columns, i just used the all symbol (astrix).
- **S_Date** is stored as **numeric** instead of **DateTime** (because it was developed a long time ago in this format)
- The total time taken to execute this query is only **4 seconds** but because of some calculations performed it is looping through ~80-90 time.

### Question

I want to know, is there any way through which i can start the searching of rows from **N**th position.

### My Approach

---

**Edit** - Currently i am using SQL Server 2008 R2 but i will switch to MySQL that is why the query is written in **SQL Server 2008 R2** format.

**Step 1**: Get first index of data by following query: -

> Select Top 1 Id from SalesInvoice where S_Date Between 20190401 And
> 20190501 order by S_Date ASC

**Step 2**: Start Searching from the returned **Id** lets say 500,000

---

### My Assumption if this technique exists

According to me, this technique might save table scanning time by starting the search from that **ID** which removes scanning of **500,000 rows**.

## BUT

I don't know how to start the lookup from a particular ID.

If anyone can provide me with a code snippet that will be very helpful

Comment: Can you update the post with the table structure including any indexes?

Comment: Create the index by `S_Date` field - it's to be enough.

Comment: "Bug":  `Between 20190401 And 20190501` will include one month plus one day.  (`BETWEEN` is 'inclusive').

Comment: @RickJames thank you for pointing that out but that is just sample data and sample query. Can you tell me how to start scanning from a particular index?

Answer (score 2):

As for "all the recorded are stored chronologically", the only control you have over this is the `PRIMARY KEY` in InnoDB.

A simple rearrangement will provide the optimal access:

```
PRIMARY KEY(S_Date, id),  -- to order the data in the order desired
INDEX(id)   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

(`TOP 1` is not a MySQL construct; see `LIMIT`.  But it is not needed with the above change.)

(The technique above is even better than INDEX(S_date).)

**Explanation**

In MySQL, the *data* rows are ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Said another way: The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  This implies that you you fetch the rows in PK order, you will be fetching the data in the most optimal order.

With the change I proposed, the data will be ordered by `S_Date` (with dups ordered by `id`).  This is exactly the order you want.

To change the current table definition, do

```
ALTER TABLE SalesInvoice
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(S_date, id),
    ADD index(id);
```

The auto_increment column must occur first in some index.  This allows the 'next' value can be efficiently found after a restart.

**Stop after**

> start the searching of rows from Nth position.

This performs such, but not efficiently:

```
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 20000
```

will skip (that is, read and discard) 20K rows, then deliver 1000.

It is more efficient to "remember where you left off".  With `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, it is straight-forward and efficient:

```
WHERE id > $leftoff
ORDER BY id
```

With a composite index it gets messier, but still possible.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: Sorry "Rick," i am unable to understand what actual work it is performing. Can you tell me how this works?

Comment: See update to my Answer @Agent_Spock

Comment: @RickJames Best solution. Just wanted to understand, why mysql doesn't allow creating table without index on 'id'?

Comment: @sql-no - I added another sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in my local and it is working fine, hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT Id FROM SalesInvoice 
WHERE S_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY S_Date ASC, Id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Result: 500000 (Assumed)

```
EXPLAIN -- Remove this when you actually want result.
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RoNum
              , Id -- Add any fields needed here (or replace ID by *)
        FROM SalesInvoice WHERE Id > 500000
) AS tbl 
WHERE S_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY tbl.S_Date ASC, tbl.Id ASC;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is not terribly efficient -- The inner query will (at least) read all the rows from id=500000 to the end of the table; then it will reread all of those, filtering on S_Date; then sort; and finally deliver the results.